# How to keep the checkbox inside gridview checked based on certain condition?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I have a gridview on my web for and checkbox inside the template field. I am having a field in database which holds integer value 0 or 1. 0 for enable and 1 for disable. When I check my checkbox it inserts 1 for that particular field in database and vice-versa. Now I want that when I open this page, so the rows with value 1 in the table should remain checked and rows with the value 0 in the table should remain unchecked.I have tried doing this-
this is my aspx page-

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridMain" runat="server" Width="1000px" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" onrowdatabound="GridMain_RowDataBound">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Student Name">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblname" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("name") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Enable/Disable">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkenbl" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
                        oncheckedchanged="chkenbl_CheckedChanged" 
                        Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("en_dis")) %>' />
                    <br />
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("id") %>'></asp:Label>
                    &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("en_dis") %>' 
                        Visible="False"></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

this my cs page-

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            show();

        }
        //chkbind();
    }
    public void show()
    {
        try
        {
            dt = g1.return_dt("select id,name,en_dis from tbl_data_show order by name");
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                adsource = new PagedDataSource();
                adsource.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
                adsource.PageSize = 5;
                GridMain.DataSource = adsource;
                GridMain.DataBind();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
protected void chkenbl_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)sender;
            //CheckBox chk = sender as CheckBox;
            //CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkenbl");
            GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)chk.NamingContainer;
            if (chk.Checked)
            {
                try
                {
                    //Label lblid = (Label)GridMain.FindControl("Label1");
                    //Label lblid = new Label();
                    //lblid.Text = GridMain.FindControl("Label1").ToString();
                    string lblid = ((Label)row.FindControl("Label1")).Text;
                    rows = g1.ExecDB("update tbl_data_show set en_dis='1' where id=" + lblid);
                    if (rows > 0)
                    {
                        Response.Write("Rows Effected Successfull.");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Response.Write(ex.ToString());
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //Label lblid1 = (Label)GridMain.FindControl("Label1");
                //Label lblid1 = new Label();
                //lblid1.Text = GridMain.FindControl("Label1").ToString();
                string lblid1 = ((Label)row.FindControl("Label1")).Text;
                rows = g1.ExecDB("update tbl_data_show set en_dis='0' where id=" + lblid1);
                if (rows > 0)
                {
                    Response.Write("Rows Effected Successfull.");
                }
            }
    }
protected void GridMain_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            dt = g1.return_dt("select en_dis from tbl_data_show");
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
               // CheckBox chk1 = new CheckBox();
                CheckBox chk1 = (CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("chkenbl");
                //CheckBox
                if (dt.Rows[0]["en_dis"] == "0")
                {

                    chk1.Checked = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    chk1.Checked = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Please guide me where I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In markup you can add `Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("en_dis")) %>'`. See example below:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkenbl" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("en_dis")) %>' oncheckedchanged="chkenbl_CheckedChanged" />
```

**OR**

1. Use `OnRowDataBound` event of gridview.
2. Make an asp hidden field to keep the value of `en_dis` column of your datatable using same Eval function.
3. Find Checkbox control and make it checked or unchecked based on the value retrieved from hidden field control.

Comment: As suggested by you I have made changes in my code. Please check. But I am getting this error- Specified cast is not valid.

Comment: @Omi. If you are making changes in `markup` then you should try updated solution. If null is possible value instead of `0` or `1` then you must use `Convert.ToBoolean`

Comment: I am storing only 1 or 0 in en_dis field of my table.
1- if checkbox is checked.
0- if checkbox is unchecked

Comment: have you tried this `Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("ColumnValue")) %>'` in markup without using `OnRowDataBound` event?

Comment: Yes I have tried this with rowdatabound. By doing this all the checkbox get's checked

Comment: I made changes in my checkbox as suggested by you. I am updating my question again. Please guide me where I am doing wrong.

Comment: I have identified few wrong doing. First you have to try this just delete `onrowdatabound="GridMain_RowDataBound"` from markup and tell  if it works?

Comment: Yes now I am getting the values with 1 in the table is checked. This is after removing OnRowDataBound class.

Comment: But please tell me what was my mistake within the code.

Comment: Actually you are implementing both solutions. Either you have to setup checkbox in markup or you could use `OnRowDataBound`. If you simply have to decide on the base of `0` and `1` then you don't need to use `OnRowDataBound`. If you have to do some complex task on the basis of column value then you could use the event. In that case you should not use labels to keep value instead use `asp hidden field`

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy for explaining the process in a very simpler way. Thanks a ton :-)

Answer (score 0):

You cant make checkbox checked in pageload event you have to use rowdatabound for it like this

```
 protected void GridViewRowEventHandler(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
 //here comes your code for checking or make it unchecked   
    }
    }
```

and in asp you can do this

```
<asp:GridView OnRowDataBound="GridViewRowEventHandler"....>
```

hope that gonna help you

Answer (score 0):

To check the checkbox according to the values stored in the database first you need to fetch those values in an array or datatable etc..
then after the data is bind to the gridview you need to use this code.

```
for (int i = 0; i < gvShowReport.Rows.Count; i++)
         {
             if(vdt.Rows[i]["status"].ToString()=="True")
             {
                 CheckBox CheckRow = ((CheckBox)gvShowReport.Rows[i].FindControl("cbCheckRow"));
                 CheckRow.Checked = true;
             }
             else
             {
                 CheckBox CheckRow = ((CheckBox)gvShowReport.Rows[i].FindControl("cbCheckRow"));
                 CheckRow.Checked = false;
             }
         }
```

gvShowReport is the id of the gridview control and vdt is the datatable containing status column with values 0(False) and 1(True)